# Can someone help me get Grub off my Pc?

Tags: windows-7, grub

I had my computer dual booted with Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux. My computer hasn't been running well at all, so I thought I'd use the nifty recovery program it came up with (which reinstalls my computer to it's factory settings from a partition).
Anyway, I was about to run that recovery, until I decided to delete the partition which held Ubuntu. And when I went to restart my computer for recovery, I was met by a Grub rescue screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what make/model? recovery systems arn't standardised.

Comment: Duplicates ["error: no such partition. in GRUB"](http://superuser.com/questions/305830/).  The difference between Windows XP and Windows 7 is unimportant, since it's actually GRUB that is the problem locus.

Comment: @JdeBP in both cases thou a potential answer is to get Windows to reinstall it's own bootloader, which I believe is different between the two versions (7 is pretty much automatic while XP requires intervention at the recovery console IIRC). Additionally, the linked question cannot use standard bootable install CD, so is much more constrained than this question.

Comment: You haven't read the first answer to the duplicate question, which shows one way to boot the WRE without using a CD.  These incidentals don't change the main thrust of the question, which in both duplicate cases is that GRUB is complaining and bringing up the rescue prompt because the questioner changed the partition table and pulled the rug out from beneath it.

Comment: And now there's a third duplicate, in two days, on ServerFault as well: ["grub rescue prompt"](http://serverfault.com/questions/286911/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Windows 7 install CD then booting into the Repair mode. [This guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) includes screenshots, but the summary is:

1. Boot using the install CD
2. Select "Repair your computer" in the bottom-left
3. Select the Windows 7 partition
4. Chose *Startup Repair*
5. Wait

Comment: Notice that it's step #1 that is the doozy that the questioner is asking about, and which you haven't directly answered yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to restore Windows-like MBR code. Note that the Windows partition needs to have the `active` flag set.

Answer (score 0):

try Acronis OS Selector from boot CD.