# error: no such partition. in GRUB

Tags: grub, rescue

I was a bit of an idiot and wiped my old Ubuntu partition whilst in Windows XP, forgetting to fix the MBR. Rebooting gives:

```
error: no such partition.
grub rescue>
```

The only things I've entered that do anything are `set`, which gives:

```
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

and `ls`, which gives:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

I have no CD drive so I can't boot from CD, but I should be able to boot from USB (haven't tested it as I need to go find one first). Is there anything I can do to fix it without external media, and if not how would I go about fixing it from USB?

Answer (score 1):

Try running these commands on the GRUB command line:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod chain
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
chainloader (hd0,msdos1)+1
```

If that fails, try using `msdos2` in place of `msdos1`.

If you get it to to boot that way, you'll have to do that every time until you replace that bootloader.

To fix it from a USB drive, you'd either need to use a Linux LiveUSB to reinstall GRUB (the easiest way being just to reinstall Linux, although it is possible just install a GRUB partition for bootloading), or [copy a Windows XP install CD to a USB drive and make it bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive) and [use the Recovery Console in Windows Setup to replace the Windows bootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/88399/repairing-the-windows-xp-mbr).